# If my program is written using JDK 8, do all of my dependencies need to use JDK 8, not JDK 6? How is it different from JDK in build tools?

Tags: java, compilation

My intuition to the first question is yes. For the 2nd question, I did see in my work, someone use JDK8 with ANT, then compile the an old package written with JDK6 to 1.6. I got really confused.

Comment: Nope. Older versions are absolutely fine. The Java compiler can target older versions too. So you can use libraries compiled for older versions of Java from newer, and you can compile for running on older versions of Java from newer. Java is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally java is backwards compatible for all versions. See [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) for details.

> Java SE 8 is strongly compatible with previous versions of the Java
>   platform. Almost all existing programs should run on Java SE 8 without
>   modification.